# GSAP Animations not loading in production

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gsap

I am working on a personal portfolio with Gatsby and GSAP for animation. It works in development but not in production. I have check and read most solutions but seems to not work and they're all old. I am using React Hooks as well.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { TweenMax, Power3, TimelineLite } from "gsap"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Projects = ({ title, text, img, link, linkText }) => {
  let app = useRef(null)
  let image = useRef(null)
  let contents = useRef(null)

  let tl = new TimelineLite({ delay: 0.8 })

  useEffect(() => {
    //For Header
    TweenMax.to(app, 0, {
      css: { visibility: "visible" },
    })

    //Image
    tl.from(image, 1.2, { y: 20, ease: Power3.easeOut }, "Start").from(
      image.firstElementChild,
      2,
      {
        scale: 1.6,
        ease: Power3.easeOut,
      },
      0.2
    )

    //Contents Animation
    const headlineFirst = contents.children[0]
    const headlineSecond = headlineFirst.nextSibling
    const headlineThird = headlineSecond.nextSibling

    tl.staggerFrom(
      [headlineFirst, headlineSecond, headlineThird],
      1,
      {
        y: 50,
        opacity: 0,
        ease: Power3.easeOut,
        delay: 0.8,
      },
      0.15,
      "Start"
    )
  }, [tl])

  return (
    <div
      ref={el => (app = el)}
      className="flex flex-wrap my-16 lg:my-20 px-4 lg:px-0"
    >
      <div className="w-full lg:w-3/5">
        <div ref={el => (image = el)} className="image-hover">
          <Img fluid={img} />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="w-full lg:w-2/5 lg:pl-10 mt-4 lg:mt-0">
        <div className="h-full flex justify-center items-center">
          <div ref={el => (contents = el)}>
            <h3 className="text-3xl">{title}</h3>
            <p className="text-lg">{text}</p>
            <a className="project-link text-base lg:text-lg" href={link}>
              Visit {linkText}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Projects
```

I hope someone can help me, this has to go live today. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. In the case anyone is having the same issue. This is the solution and it worked for me.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import gsap from "gsap"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Projects = ({ title, text, img, link, linkText }) => {
  let app = useRef(null)
  let image = useRef(null)
  let contents = useRef(null)

  const [tl] = useState(gsap.timeline({ delay: 0.8 }))

  useEffect(() => {
    //For Header
    tl.to(app, 0, {
      css: { visibility: "visible" },
    })

    //Image
    tl.from(image, 1.2, { y: 20, ease: "power3.easeOut" }, "Start").from(
      image.firstElementChild,
      2,
      {
        scale: 1.6,
        ease: "power3.easeOut",
      },
      0.2
    )

    //Contents Animation
    const headlineFirst = contents.children[0]
    const headlineSecond = headlineFirst.nextSibling
    const headlineThird = headlineSecond.nextSibling

    tl.staggerFrom(
      [headlineFirst, headlineSecond, headlineThird],
      1,
      {
        y: 50,
        opacity: 0,
        ease: Power3.easeOut,
        delay: 0.8,
      },
      0.15,
      "Start"
    )
  }, [tl])

  return (
    <div
      ref={el => (app = el)}
      className="flex flex-wrap my-16 lg:my-20 px-4 lg:px-0"
    >
      <div className="w-full lg:w-3/5">
        <div ref={el => (image = el)} className="image-hover">
          <Img fluid={img} />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="w-full lg:w-2/5 lg:pl-10 mt-4 lg:mt-0">
        <div className="h-full flex justify-center items-center">
          <div ref={el => (contents = el)}>
            <h3 className="text-3xl">{title}</h3>
            <p className="text-lg">{text}</p>
            <a className="project-link text-base lg:text-lg" href={link}>
              Visit {linkText}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Projects
```

I found out gsap 3 changed a whole lot. so i imported gsap from gsap and called it with useState, it worked in production

Comment: In GSAP 3, staggers are included in every tween so you should use a regular .from() tween with a stagger parameter. The duration parameter has also been depreciated, including it in the vars parameters instead. You also don't need to include the css: {} because GSAP recognizes DOM elements and automatically applies CSS properties to it for you. See the ["Top 5 Features of GSAP 3"](https://greensock.com/gsap3-features/) article for more info.

Comment: Your ease of "power3.easeOut" is also invalid. It should "power3.out" - use [the ease helper](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Eases) to get the correct formatting. Also note that out is the default so "power3" would be the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to [register](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.registerPlugin()) the globals that you are trying to use after you import them so that your build process doesn't tree shake them:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(TweenMax, Power3, TimelineLite);
```

We at GreenSock recommend that you use the [Install Helper](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation).

Comment: It's new as of GSAP 3. We recommend that you just use the improved and shortened GSAP 3 formatting instead of the old GSAP 2 formatting.